# innodb mysql can not update, search, delete some certain items in the table

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, ejabberd

I am using PHP to update/insert/delete records in MySQL innodb. I have about 4 millions vcard data which are stored in the MySQL innodb. But there is a problem for only one recored.

For this special record, I can not update, select, delete that record by the primary key. The error return is:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

MySQL version: mysql版本:5.5.21-log

I do not even know what's the potential problem, any hint?

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE vcard (
    username varchar(250) PRIMARY KEY,
    vcard mediumtext NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The table is designed from [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/sql/mysql.sql)

The search sql is: `select * from rosterusers where username = '3781353';`

Comment: If you are storing a lot of Chinese text, you might need to switch to utf8mb4.  However, some of your long indexed VARCHARs may cause trouble.

Comment: InnoDB tables should have PRIMARY KEYs, I see some without.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of my less reputation,so have to post in answer only.
This error appears when the query runs in an infinite loop. so please share your table structures and your query that you wrote.
Anyway error is probably in your `where` clause.
So,please share the information so that we can help you out with proper query.

Comment: I have added more detail in the question. Would you please have a look?

Comment: OK use:  ` select * from vcard where username = "3781353";`
Then go to MySQL workbench->Management (at the left side operation box where all the table's `Schemas` and `Management` tabs are there)->Client Connections  
And you'll find the query those are running in the background too. Just `Kill Query` which are not of use and then run your's query. 
But before everything restart the `XAMPP`(if you are using),MySQL Workbench, and the machine as well. Then follow the above process and run the query